# Bootstrap Carousel not sliding automatically when page loads/ after scroll or clicking

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I've been trying to implement a Bootstrap carousel in my project. Everything is working fine except for the automatic sliding. The automatic sliding is working fine when I am doing some other stuff in the foreground(Like adjusting CSS in VSCode) but when the page loads for the first time, as well as when I scroll or click anywhere on page, it completely gives up on sliding.

The code is standard copy/paste from bootstrap docs. I've tried many things from other users having the same problem. Nothing solves my issue. Also checked whether show animations is turned off or on in Win11/settings/accessibility/visual effects. Everything is fine there.

I don't know what's the issue and its hindering my work. Please Help out!

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>First slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Second slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Third slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
          </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
          </button>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: The code you've shown behaves normally after resizing. Please provide all the necessary details to demonstrate the problem.